# node.js Xcontroller.init() is not a function

Tags: node.js

This is my index file:

```
(function (controllers){

    var homeController = require("./homeController");

    controllers.init = function (app) {
        homeController.init(app);
    };

}) (module.exports);
```

but when I am running my program, I am getting below error:
`homeController.init is not a function`

Comment: Please post the file homeController.js

Answer (score 0):

Most likely. You need to initialize Class before using it's methods.

So try like this

```
(function (controllers){

   var homeController = require("./homeController");
   var homeControllerClass = new homeController();
   controllers.init = function (app) {
       homeControllerClass.init(app);
   };

}) (module.exports);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No this is not the case. I tried this but now it was showing error for "homeController is not a function"